# Error when escaping double quote marks

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, escaping, quotes

I have to escape the double quote marks in a mysqli query, because it is inside a section marked by double quotes (long story...).  Anyway, when I do this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, \"SELECT `is_doing` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`user_name` = '{$user}'\");
```

I get the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING)

And, for clarification, it is on the line of code shown above.

Please help me.

UPDATE: Here is the section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function announce(user_name){
document.getElementById("Divvy").innerHTML="<?php 
$user='"+user_name+"';
if($user != 'Contact list'){
$result = mysqli_query($db, \"SELECT `is_doing` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`user_name` = '{$user}'\");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
print_r($row);
}
echo $user.' is doing something that you will soon know about';
}
?>";
}
</script>
```

For various reasons, it has to be written PHP into JavaScript section messily like that

Comment: `because it is inside a section marked by double quotes` can you show some more of this section?

Comment: You cannot start string with `\"` or `\'`. This is used in strings to avoid unexpected end of string.

Comment: @amaster507 I have updated the question with more code

Comment: @user3411896 see my edited answer to view your real problem and get a better understanding of PHP interaction with JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Convert your query to

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `is_doing` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`user_name` = '{mysqli_escape_string($user)}'");
```

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see the end of the line

Comment: So you need to learn basics of strings in PHP. Visit - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: No errors now, but the query still doesn't return any viewable value.  The db connection is solid

Comment: No problem; now run the same query in MySQL and see what's the result. Maybe your query is not correct

Comment: I added a die clause but nothing happened

Comment: Did you try running your query in MySQL (e.g. PHPMyAdmin)?

Comment: yes, it worked perfectly when I subbed in a valid user name for the variable, which shows that it must be the variable that is at fault

Comment: OK, now check your `$user` by `var_dump` to see if you send a correct username; You can also `var_dump` the querystring and copy and paste in MySQL to see if it works

Answer (score 1):

You have a misunderstanding of how double quotes in and out of php code work. Only code in php enclosures `<?php` amd `?>` will be executed by php and the rest will simply be shown on the page outputed to the browser.

For instance:

```
<script>
  var myvar = "<?php print "foo bar"; ?>";
  alert(myvar);
</script>
```

Will alert

```
foo bar
```

Look at your page source and see what `document.getElementById("Divvy").innerHTML` is set equal to. There you will see your mysql errors most likely or valid output. but do not escape the strings inside of your php code simply because it is surrounded by double quotes in your html/js outside of your php open/close tags

**EDIT:**

The reason why your code is not working is because your query is returning no results because of this line:

```
$user='"+user_name+"';
```

you are trying to set a PHP variable with a JavaScript variable. which cannot be done! PHP is executed by the server and JavaScript is executed by the browser after the code is sent to the user.

**FROM COMMENT:**

```
function jstophp(){


var javavar=document.getElementById("text").value;  

document.getElementById("rslt").innerHTML=""+javavar+"";
}

function phptojs(){

var javavar2 = "I am php variable value";
alert(javavar2);
}
```

look at the actual source code. the function is simply alerting a variable that was set with PHP, not sending a variable from JavaScript to PHP to use in a PHP script.

Comment: this is the reason that AJAX is so popular because it allows JavaScript to interact with PHP like you want.

Comment: It is definitely a variable thing (although I don't know why the echo works fine), how would I do this in AJAX?

Comment: @user3411896 see response to your comment in my edit. also do some research on ajax and then post a new question if you get stuck. SO is not the place for us to show you how do do every single step.

Comment: @user3411896 your echo outputs `"+user_name+" is doing something that you will soon know about` because that is exactly what you are telling it to do. the query return no results and you probably have PHP notices turned off so you do not get warned about the undefined variable `$row` and then the php script continues to echo your string with variable that is also a string as "+user_name+"

Comment: @user3411896 JavaScript then is presented with `""+user_name+" is doing something that you will soon know about"` which it replaces the variable with its own at browser level and so you see the proper user name. look at the source code again. If the variable was being passed from JavaScript to PHP then your innerhtml set would contain the actual JavaScript variable *value* itself and not the *name*. Look at this link http://webcheatsheet.com/php/passing_javascript_variables_php.php but be careful and remember to escape all GET and POST data before using in query

Answer (score 0):

try that :

```
   $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `is_doing` 
                                FROM `users` 
                                WHERE `users`.`user_name` = '$user' ");
```

BWT are you mixing php with javascript ??